# Why can I insert a string to a datetime field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-insert

I have a table created by the code below.

```
CREATE TABLE actor (
   actor_id  smallint(5)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   first_name  varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   last_name  varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   last_update  DATETIME NOT NULL)
```

And I insert two records successfully by using the code below.

```
insert ignore into actor
values (1, "PENELOPE", "GUINESS", "2006-02-15 12:34:33"),
       (2, "NICK", "WAHLBERG", "2006-02-15 12:34:33")
```

However, I'm wondering why I don't need to change the type of the last value in each record from string to Datetime before inserting it into the table.
And when I try to replace `"2006-02-15 12:34:33"` by `str_to_date("2006-02-15 12:34:33", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")`, the insertion still works.

Comment: MySQL automatically converts types when necessary.

Comment: The value `'2006-02-15 12:34:33'` _is_ a valid datetime literal.

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE()` lets you reformat a date. If you happen to reformat it into a form that is recognized as a valid `DATETIME` (as in your example), you can use it as a `DATETIME` value. However, as others have pointed out, that is not necessary if you already have the data in the proper (string) format.